# adb.exe could not been found

Tags: android, sdk, titanium

First off all i must to say that everything is works fine till now.
I did not update Android SDK for a few month and today i've done it. Now when i want to execute `abd start-server` in cmd.exe in Windows i've this:

> Microsoft Windows XP [Версия 5.1.2600]
>
> (С) Корпорация Майкрософт, 1985-2001.
>
> C:\>adb
>
> "adb" не является внутренней или внешней
>
> командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
>
> C:>

i thought that somehow my `Path` variable does not have android-sdk paths, but it i'm sure you it does. And i have another problem. Now i can not choose any android device in Titanium Studio if i want to Run my App on the device.

Comment: Try adb.bat rather than just adb.  Also, make sure the platform-tools directory is  in your path, not just the root of the sdk.

Comment: my path variable: `...C:\!Development\AndroidSDK\tools\tools;C:\!Development\AndroidSDK\tools\platform-tools;...`

Comment: Umm, what are the ! there for?  Are those actually in your folder names?  That's a little unusual

Comment: OMG! thre is extra '\tools\' in my paths...

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below Steps. I hope it helps you .

Step 1: You know where your android-sdk is installed in your system if you did't changed the location search in ProgramFiles/Android

step 2: close eclipse.

Step 3: Copy adb.exe in android-sdk/platform-tools/ folder

Step 4: Paste that adb.exe in android-sdk/tools/ folder

Step 5: Now open eclipse go to Windows --> Preferences choose android then click browse and select android-sdk with in few minutes it shows APK levels installed in your system press Apply

Answer (score 0):

as is said there were an extra '\tools\' folder in my path variable. thx